# Alarm don't run when i want

Tags: c#, windows-phone

i have a problem with alarm with windows phone, i have to show a notification to the user when countdown is finished.

i'm trying to use the standard alarm (Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.Alarm) but it just doesn't work with me

here the code

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler;

///////////////////////

Alarm notifica = new Alarm("notifica");
notifica.ExpirationTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
notifica.RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.None;
notifica.BeginTime = DateTime.Now.Add(tempo);

if (ScheduledActionService.Find("notifica") != null) ScheduledActionService.Remove("notifica");
ScheduledActionService.Add(notifica);
```

"tempo" is the time (class TimeSpan) it have to wait before triggering the alarm

the alarm just doesn't work or send an error with ScheduledActionService (i can't give him a past time)

what's wrong here?
thank you

Comment: What is the variable `tempo`? Always some `TimeSpan` smaller than 5 minutes?

Comment: it's a timespan, and can be less or more than 5 minutes